# Invoke upi app from web application on desktop

Tags: javascript, upi

I am trying to integrate UPI in a web app. I read this(https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf), but it is only for android.

Websites like bookmyshow show upi apps to select from and on selecting on desktop, the user receives a notification on the app requesting to pay. How do I request payment from a website

Answer (score 1):

To send request for UPI apps from website, you need to integrate 3rd party payment gateway APIs (UPI collect API).